# Azure website to SQL server bad network latency

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

One of my clients is seeing inconsistent network latency between their test and live servers.

Using a page that does a simple `SELECT 1` 100 times:

```
Test website: 100 calls took: 109.405ms
Live website: 100 calls took: 396.9736ms (actually varies between 300-500ms)
```

Some pages using the EF can end up making 100-200 very simple db calls, which are fast in a normal datacenter setup, but on azure suddenly a second or two are being added on because of this seemingly high network latency.

The DB/websites weren't originally in the same resource groups, but now are. The info from MS on locating them close to each other is inconsistent, there used to be a concept called affinity groups which has been removed, now there are resource groups but it's unclear from the article on [moving them](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/resource-group-move-resources/) whether it does locate them near to each other. Specifically it claims:

> The new resource group may have a different location, but that does not change the location of the resource.

But I believe that is talking about the different worldwide datacenters rather than locale within the datacenter.

For live it's an s3 Standard Serverfarm with a p1 database, with test it's an s1 db, have updated post. DTU is down at 5%. All via the services, no VMs.

Is there anything we can do to reduce this?

Comment: Resource groups have zero to do with performance and location. The much more important question is whether the websites and databases are in the same *region* (e.g. US West).

Comment: @DavidMakogon They are all in North Europe. What are you basing that assertion on, is that a hunch or evidence backed? Resource Groups replaced Affinity Groups, which according to documentation did colocate services. The latency is now up to 1000ms, 10ms per request. It's terrible.

Comment: I'm basing it on how Azure works (disclaimer: I work for Microsoft, and work with Azure daily). Resource groups are an organizational/RBAC construct, and have nothing to do with where you place your actual resources. Any latency you're seeing is unrelated to Resource Groups (I have no idea what your latency is caused by, as you've provided no information about your web app or SQL database - not even sure if you're running SQL in VM or SQL db service). You might want to edit your question to provide more details about your setup.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Ah, ok! For live it's an s3 Standard Serverfarm with a p1 database, with test it's an s1 db, have updated post. All via the services, no VMs. DTU is consistently down at 5%. I've finished fixing a load of performance problems with bad EF queries and a poor O(n2) loop, which has significantly cut the DTU and CPU used and now they barely use anything, but the site is still much slower than I'd expect from a normal non-azure server setup and I'm trying to figure out why. Thought I'd check the SQL latency on a hunch as a couple of pages spawn 100s of queries and found this.

Comment: Why is a single page generating so many queries? o.O

Comment: @juunas Because. I didn't write it, I'm here to fix it. Also that's perfectly normal in lazy loading situations. Nor would it matter if there wasn't the equivalent of 1000km distance in latency between the website and the SQL server.